# Gradle buid spring boot questions

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I have to create lot of spring boot projects with other dependencies.

How can I create a common gradle file and inculde it in all the projects so that I can specify springboot version only in one place.
I can also keep common dependencies in that file.